# Google Contacts API not allowing more than 7 requests per second (different users)

Tags: google-api, gdata, google-api-client, google-shared-contacts

We are trying to make more than 7 requests per second (different users) to Google Contacts API and we are getting response as:

```
 <errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">

 <error>

  <domain>usageLimits</domain><code>userRateLimitExceeded</code> 

  <internalReason>User Rate Limit Exceeded</internalReason>

 </error>

</errors>
```

we are noway near to the quota "requests per 100 seconds per user"
or "requests per day".

Is there a way where we can check quota on application level ?

Comment: I've found that I can get 9/sec, but once I hit 10/second I start getting rate-limited. 10/second would give you the "1000 requests per 100 seconds" limit (if that's your quota limit), and I'm not sure why they list it as per 100 seconds instead of per second.